# Cross Platform Live Stream

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, rtsp, live-streaming

I'm new to video encoding / streaming and I am looking to create a web and mobile app which allows for live stream recording and watching across multiple platforms.

My goal is to be able to stream from iOS, Android and PC, in contrast to most current live stream platforms.

The live stream should be server to peer, and allow for multiple users to stream at the same time.

From what I researched RTSP seems to be the way to go, but it doesn't seem to be 100% compatible with Android and iOS, and from the examples I have seen, it results in a low quality stream on these devices.

Is there any better way to achieve this?
Is RTSP actually the best way to do this?